# Python scalars error Fix

Tags: python, matplotlib, logarithm, scalar

I'm trying to make an exponential fit to find the Lyapunov Exponent of this data, however, I keep getting this error:

```
m=math.log10(abs(x))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

and here's the code:

```
f=np.loadtxt('Single Small Angle 1.txt',unpack=True,skiprows=2)
g=np.loadtxt('Single Small Angle 5.txt',unpack=True,skiprows=2)

x = f-g[:,:11944]
t=range(len(x))
m=math.log10(abs(x))

np.polyfit(t,m)

plt.plot(t,abs(x))
#plt.xlabel("${\Theta}$ [rad]")
#plt.ylabel("${\Omega}$ [rad/s]")
#plt.title("Small Angle Approximation Phase Space")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `np.log10()` instead of `math.log10`. The built-in math library does not handle numpy arrays, so the numpy log10 function is more appropriate.